# Unexpected CFBundleExecutable Key in main target?

Tags: ios, xcode

I submit the app, it works in the sim and device and uploads to the store, but within minutes I get an email :

Unexpected CFBundleExecutable Key - The bundle at '/Payload/Dashboard.app/Automotive Events Mobile/Info.plist' does not contain a bundle executable. If this bundle intentionally does not contain an executable, consider removing the CFBundleExecutable key from its Info.plist and using a CFBundlePackageType of BNDL. If this bundle is part of a third-party framework, consider contacting the developer of the framework for an update to address this issue.

This makes no sense whatsoever. Dashboard.app is my main target...how can it not have an executable?

I have ${EXECUTABLE_NAME) as the Executable file in the info.plist it is referring to

Comment: Usually Info.plist is directly inside the app bundle.  The error message suggests an extra level of indirection.  What is the "Automotive Events Mobile" subfolder?

Comment: its the folder structure, so on my desktop I have a folder and then inside that folder I have the workspace, xcodeproj, podfile, pods folder, and resources folder. All the code including the plist is inside the Automotive Events Folder

Comment: Forget about workspace, did you check if the info.plist is valid at the path inside the ipa?

Comment: I got it, the Folder was being copied to the bundle resources. I removed the folder and it worked